# New Vinyl Windows: The Fit Isn't What I Expected

Tags: windows

[image: windows that rock]
I had several custom size vinyl windows (as well as a slider) installed in my home. I was told they are Milgard.  I've never installed vinyl windows before. Just now I opened one of the bedroom windows for the first time and was surprised to see, rather than sliding it first rocked in its track. Yes, it does operate as normally left to right, but I don't recall seeing that much "non lateral" rotating motion in a window.
So my questions: how much of this rotation free-play is normal/aceptable? Were these custom windows perhaps sized too small for their frame at the factory? Image linked below. Thank You.

Comment: Is there something at the top that's keeping the pane from sliding levelly?

Answer (score 0):

To facilitate installing and removing the window from the frame, the manufacturer oversizes the frame vertically. You install the window by pushing it up into the frame's top track and then rotating the bottom of the window into the lower track. This leaves a big void space above the window. Look in the upper track. There should be some spacers in there that slide around to intermittently fill the void space above the window. Space them out to prevent the rotation.

And operating the windows down low helps too. I think I may have unconsciously learned that habit, as even with the spacers placed nicely the window can still rotate a little and bump into the spacers.